# JQuery Bootstrap Multiselect dynamically bind event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using JQuery Bootstrap multiselect from here: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

It works perfectly but I want to add event handler dynamically, after multiselect is already initialized, for example:

```
$("selector").multiselect();

....

$("selector").bind('onDropdownShown', function(event) {
    ...
}
```

I'm able to add such handlers on plugin initialization (line 1), but it is important for me to do it in another part of code dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

Let's initialize the multiselect such way:

```
 $('selector').multiselect({
        onDropdownShow: function(event) {
            $(event.currentTarget).trigger("multiselectshow", event);
        }
    });
```

where `multiselectshow` is a custom event, declared specially for this case.

Then, in a document, where custom reaction is needed, let's declare such event handler:

```
$(document).on("multiselectshow", function(event) {
     console.log("Success!");
});
```

The solution allows to implement a custom handler for any plugin's built-in events outside of initialization lines and is an alternative for the only approach described in the official documentation and in The Web.